# How to list SolrCloud aliases?

Tags: solrcloud

In SolrCloud Collections API (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API), we can list collections using action:

```
/admin/collections?action=LIST
```

However, aliases are not included in this list. There is also no corresponding command for aliases (we can only `CREATEALIAS` or `DELETEALIAS`). How to list aliases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature seems to be not implemented yet: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4968

However, you can use this command:

```
/admin/collections?action=CLUSTERSTATUS
```

Each collection will be listed together with the aliases it is covered by. Also in the bottom of the XML there is a separate node, summarising all aliases and covered collections.

Answer (score 4):

The aliases list can be fetched in json format using the following command.

`[solr_server_hostname]:8983/solr/zookeeper?detail=true&path=/aliases.json`

The "data" field in this JSON holds the list of collections object.

Answer (score 1):

For Solr 6.6+, you could use:

```
/solr/admin/collections?action=LISTALIASES
```

See https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-listaliases